# selection of a item from combobox which is inside the datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `DataGridView` and two `ComboBox` columns inside. On selection of value from first ComboBox control, I am supposed to bind data in second ComboBox. But when I am selecting an item from second ComboBox same event is getting fired multiples times.

I use the following code:

```
void Grid_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    var cell = e.Control as ComboBox;
    if (cell != null)
    {
        cell.SelectedIndexChanged -= doWork;
        cell.SelectedIndexChanged += doWork;
    }
}

public void doWork(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str="";
    var tb = datagrdADDTEMP.EditingControl as ComboBox;
    if (tb.SelectedValue != null)
    {
        str = tb.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should know that the `EditingControl` ComboBox is the same for the all the columns and hence if you want the event for a particular one then you should check for the originating column in the `EditingControlShowing` event and then handle it.

Comment: please can you explain in detail with the sample code